# How to invoke devise authentication from a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building a movies website. I would like the home page (`views/movies/index.html.erb`) to display a list of all movies even to visitors who are not signed in. And I would like to provide a login link  on the home page which when clicked should invoke the authentication system of `devise` gem. How do I achieve this?

I provide this link on the home page (`views/movies/index.html.erb`)

```
<%= link_to 'Log in', login_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I have this in my `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'login', to: 'devise#new', as: 'login'
```

I have provided this dummy method in `movies_controller.rb`

```
def login
end
```

This is the new session (login) code generated by `devise` in `/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

```
<header>
<h1>
Log in
</h1>
</header>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :email %> <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %> 
<%= f.label :password %> <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %> 
<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember Me 
<% end -%> <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>     
<% end %> 
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

If I somehow invoke `/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`, would that solve my problem?

If yes, then how can I invoke this `erb` from `movies_controller`?

If no, then how else can I solve my login problem?

Comment: did you mean override your devise ?

Comment: My be your solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818866/10384879